# ActionBar Title меняется когда передвигается ViewPager нужна реализация

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

У меня есть 6 дней каждый отмечен как Пн Вт Ср Чт Пт Сб
. И не могу реализовать такую конструкцию чтобы когда Fragment activity стоят на Пн в ActionBar стоял название Понедельник и когда Вт то Вторник...

можете посмотреть Рисунок
[image: Картина]

у меня получилось реализовать в начале когда нажимаю Пн выходит Понедельник поочередно выходит и надпись меняется .....
Теперь проблема в том что Название не меняется когда с Пятницы перехожу к Четверг то ActionBar Title название остается Пятницей и все больше не меняется .... только в начале поменялось и все.... Вот код реализации

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        actionBar.setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + "Суббота" + "</font>")));

        if (position == 0){
            return new PonidelnikFragment();
        }

        if (position == 1) {
            actionBar.setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + "Понидельник" + "</font>")));
            return new VtornikFragment();
        }

        if (position == 2) {
            actionBar.setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + "Вторник" + "</font>")));
            return new SredaFragment();
        }

        if (position == 3) {
            actionBar.setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + "Среда" + "</font>")));
            return new ChetvergFragment();
        }
        if (position == 4) {
            actionBar.setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + "Четверг" + "</font>")));
            return new PyatnisaFragment();

        } if (position == 5) {
            actionBar.setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + "Пятница" + "</font>")));
        }

        return new SubbotaFragment();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот приблизительная реализация ( делал без студии поэтому мог где-то что-то не дописать). У вас должен быть адаптера для вашего бара:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

дальше вы должны создать все фрагменты с нужной вам разметкой, но я бы вам вообще советовал создать один фрагмент и его заполнять данными. Вот что у вас должно быть в mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

вот [первоисточник](https://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/).

Надеюсь что помог в решении вашей проблемы, если что-то будет непонятно - не стесняйтесь и пишите, помогу чем смогу. Удачи :)

Comment: Почему то мой position прыгает с 0 сразу к 1 и останавливается не знаю почему ....  Он сначала показывает 0 потом и  сразу 1 и все....

Comment: попробуйте через switch сделать

Comment: Попробовал тоже самое прыгает

Comment: а если пока сделать не замещение фрагментов, а просто в логи выводить текущую позицию

Comment: Пробывал не получается

Comment: что именно не получается?? логи получить?

Comment: да я через логи все смотрю

Comment: и то есть в логах тоже такое творится?

Comment: Да тоже самое (

Comment: это у вас вообще viewpager или как вы это реализуете?

Comment: я не знаю почему так не должно же быть так

Comment: Это Action Bar Tabs (widh ViewPager)

Comment: обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: я переписал Ваш код, все работает отлично, теперь я не понимаю как изменить название Action Bar(ToolBar) откуда реализовать

Comment: Ну что бы когда был 1Tab то Понедельник если 2 то Вторник

Comment: а если toolbar.setTitle или что-то типа такого?

Comment: Хорошо спасибо! работает)

Comment: если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый пожалуйста.